# How does SQL trigger affect performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a table in my postgresql table named `traffic`. My traffic table transactions fires some triggers. I have two trigger named `trigger1` and `trigger2`. When a row inderted or updated or deleted these triggers will fire. I wonder, how does SQL trigger affect the transaction performance?

If my traffic table insert transaction takes 1ms and `trigger1` takes 2ms and `trigger2` takes 3 ms, will an insert cost 1+2+3 = 6ms? Or does total insert transaction 1ms and triggers runs seperately?

Comment: Run your statements using `explain (analyze, verbose, timing)` and you will see the exact time each trigger call took

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triggers run as part of the data modifying statement, so when the statement is completed, so are the triggers. In your example, the `INSERT` will take 6 ms.

A slight exception here are *deferred constraint triggers*, which will run when the whole transaction is committed. If you are running a transaction with multiple statements, these triggers will run after the statements have completed. But the total run time of the transaction will be the same.

Comment: In this stuation, I may use queue tables to complate transaction tasks, using a programming script.

Comment: Yes, that's an option for asynchronous processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inserting/updating in bulk, you might be able to get some benefit from a statement-level trigger. Here's a good blog post on this subject from Laurenz Albe, who posted a comment to you already.

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/rules-or-triggers-to-log-bulk-updates/